# Using React with JSON response to fetch API data

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm fetching the movies API with the code below, and confused about how this works as I havent seen this particular type of fetching before, especially the line below. I know its setting the movies hook with SetMovies, but what is the .Search for

```
setMovies(jsonResponse.Search);
```

Can anyone give me a description of what this line is for

```
fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=0000000`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
            if (jsonResponse.Response === 'True') {
                setMovies(jsonResponse.Search);

                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setErrorMessage(jsonResponse.Error);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: it's a setter function to the state initialised may be like for `Movies`

Comment: Do you mean its specific to the Movies API?

Comment: Might be in JSON response getting Search as key. And its accessing those values

Comment: Yes `.Search` is where you might want the values to be to make use further ...and setMovies -  it would be defined something as `const [Movies,setMovies] = useState([])` in your code and later using the second value which is a setter for Movies in state ....  [see this for a better idea](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)